# Next.js authentication : 404 error for authentication

Tags: reactjs, authentication, next.js, http-post, strapi

I've an **404 error** for **authentication**.
I used **Strapi** api for backend.
heres errors console messages :

> api.js?4749:30 POST http://localhost:3000/undefinedapi/auth/signin 404
> (Not Found) Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in
> JSON at position 0

Here's my code.

***.env***

```
REACT_APP_API_URL='http://localhost:1337/'
```

Why result of **REACT_APP_API_URL** is *undefined* and not *http://localhost:1337/*?

***api.js***

```
export function getStrapiURL(path = "") {
      return `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}${path}`;
}

export async function loginAPI(path, creds) {
   let token = '';

   const config = {
     method: 'POST',
     headers: {
       "Content-Type": "application/json"
     },
     body: JSON.stringify(creds)
};

const requestUrl = getStrapiURL(path);
    console.log(process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL,'--->',requestUrl);
    const response = await fetch(requestUrl, config);
    token = await response.headers.get('authorization');
    console.log('response => ',response)
    const user = await response.json();

    if (user.data) {
      Cookies.set('token', token.split(' ')[1], { secure: true });
      Cookies.set('id', user.data.id, { secure: true });
    }
}
```

***login.js***

```
import React, { createRef } from 'react'
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

import { loginAPI } from './api/api'
import FullImageComponent from '../components/Container/FullImageComponent'
import imgPhProfile from '../public/images/ph-profile.png'

export default function login() {
  const history = useHistory()
  const emailEl = createRef()
  const passwordEl = createRef()

  const handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log('==>',process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL);
    const creds = {
      user: {
        email: emailEl.current.value,
        password: passwordEl.current.value
      }
    }
    console.log('creds ==>',creds.user);

    loginAPI('api/auth/signin', creds)
    //history.push('/');
  }

  return (<>
    <FullImageComponent imgProfile={imgPhProfile}/>
    <section className="container d-flex flex-column align-items-center justify-content-center h-100 my-5 pt-5">
        <h1>Connexion</h1>
        <form className="w-form" onSubmit={**handleSubmit**}>
          <div className="mb-3">
            <label htmlFor="email"
                   className="form-label"></label>
            <input type="email" 
                   ref={emailEl} 
                   className="form-control" 
                   id="email" 
                   placeholder="email" />
          </div>
          <div className="mb-3">
            <label htmlFor="password" 
                   className="form-label"></label>
            <input type="password" 
                   ref={passwordEl} 
                   className="form-control" 
                   id="password" 
                   placeholder="password" />
          </div>
          <div className="mt-5 mb-3">
            <button type="submit" 
                    className="">Valider</button>
          </div>
        </form>
    </section>
  </>)
}
```

**EDIT:**

I've modify the variable name in:

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL='http://localhost:1337/'
```

Now, here's the new errors console:

> POST http://localhost:1337/api/login 405 (Method Not Allowed) Uncaught
> (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token M in JSON at position 0

Comment: Does this help answer your question: [How to properly set environmental variable for Nextjs app on Vercel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66293848/how-to-properly-set-environmental-variable-for-nextjs-app-on-vercel)? You have to prefix the variable with `NEXT_PUBLIC_` to expose it to the browser.

Comment: The 405 (Method Not Allowed) status code indicates that your API endpoint doesn't allow POST requests. Can you add the code for your `/api/login` endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, since I use qrapgQl for queries I should add `/graphql` at the end of the production URL

```
const prodEndpoint = `${NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}/graphql`
```

as we do for `localhost:1337/graphql`.

But also I have been found that you should remove the last slash when setting `NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL`.