# Nextjs process.env variables not working even after deployed on Vercel

Tags: javascript, next.js, environment-variables

So I have a project that has 4 api keys that I need hidden:

```
STORYBLOK_API_KEY= 
EMAILJS_SERVICE_ID= 
EMAILJS_USER_ID= 
EMAILJS_TEMPLATE_ID=
```

All 4 of them I am using with `process.env.XXX`, the funny thing is that, the storyblok key is working (but it is not used within a component), however the other 3 I am using within a form submission function:

```
 const sendContactForm = async (formData) => {
      const data = {
        service_id: process.env.EMAILJS_SERVICE_ID,
        template_id: process.env.EMAILJS_TEMPLATE_ID,
        user_id: process.env.EMAILJS_USER_ID,
        template_params: { ...formData, form: "Discover form" },
      };
      try {
        const response = await axios.post("https://api.emailjs.com/api/v1.0/email/send", data);
        console.log(response);
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
      }
    };
```

And they are not working here, they are undefined. I have tried:

- dev server
- build and start the production server
- deploy on Vercel and set the environment variables there

All 3 approaches did not work.

Comment: Are you trying to access the variables on the client side?

Comment: @Darkbound what is the name of the file in which you store the variables?

Comment: @PsyGik yes, that is what I am tryign to do

Comment: @MarioG8 .env.local, but like I said its not working even when deployed to Vercel and setting the variables on their side.

Comment: [By default environment variables are only available in the Node.js environment, meaning they won't be exposed to the browser. In order to expose a variable to the browser you have to prefix the variable with `NEXT_PUBLIC_`.](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables#exposing-environment-variables-to-the-browser)

Comment: Does this answer your question: [How to properly set environment variables in Next.js app deployed to Vercel?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66294209/1870780)?

Comment: Did the answers solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Did you read [**documentation**](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables) exactly? How we can add `Environment Variables` in `Next.js?` Below you have simple example from docs.

**.env.local**

```
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_USER=myuser
DB_PASS=mypassword
```

This loads `process.env.DB_HOST`, `process.env.DB_USER`, and `process.env.DB_PASS` into the **Node.js** environment automatically allowing you to use them in `Next.js` data **fetching methods** and **API routes.**

example:

```
// pages/index.js
export async function getStaticProps() {
  const db = await myDB.connect({
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    username: process.env.DB_USER,
    password: process.env.DB_PASS,
  })
  // ...
}
```

---

`Environment variables` are only available in the `Node.js`(serverside
) environment, meaning they won't be exposed to the browser.
In order to **expose** a variable to the browser(clientside) you have to prefix the variable with `NEXT_PUBLIC_.` For example:

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_ANALYTICS_ID=123456xyzabcde
```

---

Here You Have All examples of using [environment-variables](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/environment-variables)
in Next.js . Good Luck ;-)